# heading and image not aligning in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code

```css
header img{
 width:10%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
header h1{ 
 text-align: right;
 display:inline;
 position: absolute;
}
header {
 width : 100%;
 height: 1% ;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "css\main.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/12/15/09/31/badge-1093966_640.png" alt="">
    <h1>KUNAL MEHTA</h1>
    </div>
    </header>
    <section>
    
    </section>
    <footer>
    
    </footer>

    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What i am talking about is that i want the h1 to go to right and they both should align in the center of the parent Element.i am using BOOTSTRAP so answers with bootstraps are encouraged

Comment: Center horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: Both horizontally and Vertically

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use flex for that- And I truly recommend using it, since it makes the solution much cleaner and easier to maintain. Please note I only had to change the container element for making this solution, and clean the h1 margin.

```
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px
}

.container-fluid h1 {
  margin: 0
}

header {
    background: red;
}

header img{
    width:10%;
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)